# Program UIButton to open Facebook app to specific page, and same for twitter and instagram

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, twitter, instagram

I am building an app that when you click a button labeled "Facebook", "Twitter", or "Instagram", it will open the respective app and take you to the specific page I set. I've been searching non-stop for answers for the last week, if anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it!

I have been all over StackOverflow and other forums and videos and cannot find the answer to this question. Either the solutions I find are outdated and do not work anymore or are not exactly what I want.

Comment: you are talking about public pages?

Comment: What coding examples have you tried?

Comment: @IBAction func FBButtonPressed( sender: Any) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please note**: typically a question like this is not going to get very useful answers on SO. In the future, try to be more specific and show a little work. However, I appreciate how it can be difficult to search for a solution when you don't know the correct terminology. The term you are looking for is "URL scheme"

---

Each app has its own URL schemes for opening specific pages and/or websites. You will need to check their documentation and/or search online to see if you can find the URL schemes you need. There was an unofficial website listing a lot of these, but it is no longer maintained.

For example, to open a specific Facebook profile page (could be a person, or a company, etc) use:`fb://profile/<page id>"` replacing the  with the Facebook ID corresponding to the page. This is a numeric value, you can find it sometimes in the URL, but http://findmyfbid.com/ is a useful resource for this. 
Then you can simply trigger [`open`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open) on the shared `UIApplication` instance to open the URL. But keep in mind the user may not have Facebook installed, so you should use [`canOpenURL`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open) to check if the URL scheme you are trying to use is supported, and if not you can just open the URL in a browser.

However, some apps may have implemented the new features for [Universal linking](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html), so the device may automatically open the appropriate page if you just provide a standard URL, like `https://facebook.com/<page_id>`. I suggest playing around with it.

Note, for each URL scheme you want to be able to check `canOpenURL` with, you will need to [add it](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-SW11) to your app's plist.

Since I already have Instagram and Twitter handy here are their basic schemes for opening a user's page:

`instagram://user?username=<username>`

`twitter://user?screen_name=<username>`

Note: there are other URL schemes that these apps support (e.g. you could link to a location page, or a specific tag, on Instagram) so you should check their [docu](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)men[tation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs) for more information on URL schemes.

Comment: @IBAction func FBButtonPressed( sender: Any) {
        if UIApplication.shared.conOpenURL(NSURL(string: "fb://profile/ <profile ID>")! as URL) {
             UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "fb://profile/ <profile ID>")! as URL)
} else {
     UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(String: "https://facebook.com/ <profile>")! as URL)

Comment: Does not work as in what? Crashes? Nothing happens? What?

By the way you wrote "conOpenURL", and your "facebook.com <profile>" should be "https://www.facebook.com/<profile>" (again make sure to put a profile ID instead of <profile>)

Also, I suggest you put your code into your question.